# C#: WriteFile with Line Breaks

Tags: c#, file, save

I have several web site files that I have to edit systematically. Therefore, I have written a small program that changes certain lines. I read the content with

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(
                        File.ReadAllLines(fileName,
                                          Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
                                    );
```

make the changes, and save the content with

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
file.WriteLine(content);
```

Sadly, this saves the content in one single line without line breaks. Could you please tell me which other function I have to use or how I have to adjust the code so the original line breaks don't get lost in the process of writing the file?

Comment: What the "content" in here? show us the more related code

Comment: The content is only like `<html><head><title>The Title</title></head> ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx) method instead:

As per MSDN:

> Creates a new file, writes one or more strings to the file, and then closes the file.

Code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(
                    File.ReadAllLines(fileName,
                                      Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
                                );
// ... do something (editing) ... 
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, list);
```